# Ionic3 Opentok session.connect doesn;t work

Tags: android, session, ionic3, opentok

I'm using ionic3 with `cordova-plugin-opentok@3.2.2` 
My session is created by node.js back end and that returns session ID and token without any issues.

When I use that token to connect to a session, the call never returns (in error hander code) and on my mobile, I see a window on android phone but without any streaming from my camera.

Tried upgrading to 3.4.2 plugin, but then that gives errors on gradle. Looked at many exchanges on stack overflow and the Q&A's on the plugin documentation.

```
startCall() {

    // Get the session ID and Token from the server  
  this.discussionService.initiateVideoCall({userId:this.selUser._id.toString(),slot:this.slotDetails}).subscribe(callDetails => {
        this.callDetails = callDetails;
        this.token = this.callDetails.token;
        this.sessionId = this.callDetails.sessionId;
        //this.startVideoCall();
    });

}
startVideoCall() {
    this.session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);
    this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher');

    this.session.on({
    streamCreated: (event: any) => {
        this.session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber');
        OT.updateViews();
    },
    streamDestroyed: (event: any) => {
        console.log(`Stream ${event.stream.name} ended because ${event.reason}`);
        OT.updateViews();        
    },
    sessionConnected: (event: any) => {
        this.session.publish(this.publisher);
    }
    });

    this.session.connect(this.token, (error: any) => {
        <<< The line below never gets executed>>>>
if (error) {
                console.log(`There was an error connecting to the session ${error}`);
            }
        });
        this.session.publish(this.publisher);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Previously, there was an issue with the Cordova OpenTok Plugin because it did not support the `error` handler for the `session.connect` method. This was fixed with [Release v3.4.3](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/releases/tag/v3.4.3).

If you're unable to upgrade, you can remove the `error` handler from your implementation and call connect and publish like so:

```
this.session.on({
    sessionConnected: (event: any) => {
        this.session.publish(this.publisher);
    },
});

this.session.connect(this.token);
```

However, I highly recommend upgrading so you can verify if there was an error before attempting to publish. If you're unable to upgrade because there is an issue  with the plugin, please file it [here](https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues).

Comment: Sorry for a late response. I will eventually upgrade to lates, but Wanted to make current thing work. I had made a blunder in session object creation ("this.session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);" whereI was passing blank apiKey. However even after fixing that, I'm still not seeing my own video stream and neither do I get a call back event                                                                                          
this.session.on({
    sessionConnected: (event: any) => {
        this.session.publish(this.publisher);
    },
});

Comment: I have also set debug level "OT.setLogLevel(OT.DEBUG); But I'm not seeing any errors in console either. Please suggest.

Comment: Hmm, could you please check the sessionId logs in https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/inspector_doc/ and see if you're seeing any errors? The log level is only for the JS SDK, you would have to look at the native logs. Lastly, I recommend filing an issue here: https://github.com/opentok/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues